# Update ChildViewController from UIPageViewController when embeded in NavigationController swift4

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, swift4, uipageviewcontroller

I have a UIPageViewController embeded in a NavigationController [image: app setup]
I'm adding programically a editButton to the UIPageViewController's navigationItem.
I would like to update the child viewController UI when the UIPageviewcontroller set Editing changing state.
What is the simpliest way to do this?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with [RxSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift)

Declare a variable like

```
`var isEditingEnabled = Variable<Bool>(false)`
```

in Page Controller

and in child view controller's viewDidLoad add an observer like

```
parentVCObj.isEditingEnabled.asObservable().subscribe{

}
```

Comment: let me know you don't understand. Go through the documentation of RxSwift. It will be very helpful and neat way to achieve this

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will look to this asap.